# getting ImportError: cannot import name 'create_proxy' from 'pyodide' (/lib/python311.zip/pyodide/__init__.py) whyle working with pyscript

Tags: python, html, importerror, pyscript

I am learning about pyscript and I am trying to make a wordle game. So far it is all going well exept that I am getting this "ImportError: cannot import name 'create_proxy' from 'pyodide' (/lib/python311.zip/pyodide/**init**.py)" error.

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
    
            body{
              margin: 0px;
              padding: 0px;
              background-color: #011627;
              color: #fdfffc;
              text-align: center;
              background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/02/10/13/sky-828648_960_720.jpg);
              background-position: center;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: cover;
              height: 100vh;
            }
            h1{
              font-size: 65px;
              font-family: 'Comfortaa';
            }
          
            input{
              width: 75px;
              height: 55px;
              border-radius: 10px;
              font-size: 44px;
              margin: 10px;
          
            }
          
            .btn:hover{
              background-color:green;
              cursor: pointer;
            }
          
            
            </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>

    

    <body>
        <p>Guess a word (5 letters)</p> 
        <p id="guesses">Number of guesses: 0</p>
        <input type="text" id="guess" name="guess" style="width: 370px; height: 70px; background-color: #4c555c;color: white;"/><br /><br />
        <input type="button" id="guessBTN" name="guess" style="width: 750px; height: 70px; background-color: #0091ff;color: white;"/>
        <p id="colors"></p>
        <py-script>
            from js import document
            from pyodide import create_proxy

            #for each guess w, compare with last word(ans)
            #list of result

            ans = robot
            tries = 6
            def guess(current):
                currentL = list(current)
                List_Of_Ans = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                for s in range(len(List_Of_Ans)): #letter is the letter that we are testing first one is R Route
                    listAns = list(ans)
                    Rletter = listAns[s]
                    Tletter = currentL[s]
                    if (Rletter == Tletter):
                        List_Of_Ans[s] = 2
                        #print(List_Of_Ans)
                        listAns.remove(Rletter)
                #print(listAns)
                #print()
                for s in range(len(List_Of_Ans)): #letter is the letter that we are testing first one is R Route
                    if List_Of_Ans[s] == 2:
                        continue
                
                    Tletter = currentL[s]
                    #print(s, Tletter)
                    if(Tletter in listAns):
                        List_Of_Ans[s] = 1
                        #print(List_Of_Ans)
                        #print(listAns)
                        listAns.remove(Tletter)
                        #print(listAns)
                for z in range(len(List_Of_Ans)):
                    if(List_Of_Ans[z] == 1):
                        List_Of_Ans[z] = "YELLOW"
                    if(List_Of_Ans[z] == 2):
                        List_Of_Ans[z] = "GREEN"
                    if(List_Of_Ans[z] == 0):
                        List_Of_Ans[z] = "GRAY"
                pyscript.write(List_Of_Ans[0], List_Of_Ans[1], List_Of_Ans[2], List_Of_Ans[3], List_Of_Ans[4])
                if (List_Of_Ans == ["GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN"]):
                    pyscript.write(f"YAY you got it in {x+1} tries !!!")
            guess_proxy = create_proxy(guess)
            guess_button = document.getElementById("guessBTN")
            guess_button.addEventListener("click", guess_proxy)
        </py-script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pretty simple,
I will be open to suggestions

I am trying to make a small wordle game

I just want to not get this error for right now, later I will try to add some more features.

thank you

Comment: Looks like `create_proxy` is in `pyodide.ffi`, not directly in `pyodide`.

Comment: Why are you trying to import it from there?  Are you following some example?

Comment: no I just googled it up and this is what I should have done. What should I do instead?

Comment: Import it from the submodule, as I already said.  `from pyodide.ffi import create_proxy`

Comment: Indeed, `create_proxy` got moved to that submodule in Pyodide 0.21 and later, so in PyScript 2022.09.1 and later. However, Pyodide still supported importing those names from the base module until Pyodide 0.23, so in PyScript 2023.05.1 when they were removed. (2023.05.1 is `/latest` at the time of your question.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `create_proxy` from `pyodide.ffi`.
Your code should become:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.1.1/core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.1.1/core.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>

    

    <body>
    <button>Click Me!</button>
        <py-script>
            from js import document
            from pyodide.ffi import create_proxy
            element = document.querySelector("button")
            def button_click(event):
                print("Button clicked!", event)
            click_proxy = create_proxy(button_click)
            element.addEventListener("click", click_proxy)
            </py-script>
    </body>
</html>
```